# Mongo-Hadoop simple test failing with NPE

Tags: java, mongodb, hadoop, nullpointerexception, mapreduce

This is an open issue posted in the support forum [here](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/ec4ce08178a949a5/e002c043f41030d5?pli=1) but since I didn't get any response, I thought I should try asking here.

I have an existing application that uses MongoDB as the 
data layer. Currently I am using Mongo's Map reduce mechanism but, I 
am facing some performance issues. So I thought of using Hadoop to 
implement that logic.

I have run the treasury-yield example with success and thought of 
creating a simple project just to get to know the mongo-hadoop driver. 
So I created a project inserted the appropriate jar files in the build 
path and run it.

This is my java code:

```
final Configuration conf = new Configuration(); 
    MongoConfigUtil.setInputURI( conf, "mongodb:// 
                          username:passw...@192.168.1.198/locations" ); 
    MongoConfigUtil.setOutputURI( conf, "mongodb://localhost/ 
                                 test.out" ); 
    System.out.println( "Conf: " + conf ); 
    final Job job = new Job( conf, "word count" ); 
    job.setJarByClass( WordCount.class ); 
    job.setMapperClass( TokenizerMapper.class ); 
    job.setCombinerClass( IntSumReducer.class ); 
    job.setReducerClass( IntSumReducer.class ); 
    job.setOutputKeyClass( Text.class ); 
    job.setOutputValueClass( IntWritable.class ); 
    job.setInputFormatClass( MongoInputFormat.class ); 
    job.setOutputFormatClass( MongoOutputFormat.class ); 
    System.exit( job.waitForCompletion( true ) ? 0 : 1 );"
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Conf: Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml 
12/05/20 14:12:03 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native- 
hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where 
applicable 
12/05/20 14:12:03 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for 
parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the 
same. 
12/05/20 14:12:03 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User 
classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or 
JobConf#setJar(String). 
12/05/20 14:12:03 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area 
file:/tmp/hadoop-maximos/mapred/staging/maximos1261801897/.staging/ 
job_local_0001 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java: 
796) 
        at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer.doGetCollection(DBApiLayer.java:116) 
        at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer.doGetCollection(DBApiLayer.java:43) 
        at com.mongodb.DB.getCollection(DB.java:81) 
        at 
com.mongodb.hadoop.util.MongoSplitter.calculateSplits(MongoSplitter.java: 
51) 
        at 
com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat.getSplits(MongoInputFormat.java: 
51) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java: 
962) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:979) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:174) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:897) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:850) 
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416) 
        at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.j ava: 
1093) 
        at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java: 
850) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:500) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:530) 
        at 
com.mongodb.hadoop.examples.wordcount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java: 
100)
```

What I am doing wrong? is this a Mongo, Hadoop or Mongo-Hadoop problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to specify the name of your collection (that you are getting the data from).

In the example the line looks like this:

```
MongoConfigUtil.setInputURI( conf, "mongodb://localhost/test.in" );
```

However, in your code I see:

```
MongoConfigUtil.setInputURI( conf, "mongodb:// 
                      username:passw...@192.168.1.198/locations" );
```

I'm not sure if locations is the collection name or database name, if it's the collection, then you can try prefixing it with the database name.  If it's the database, add .yourcollectionname to the end of it.